# Temp table not found in another Dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a temp table in Dynamic query

```
declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max)='select * into #table_1 from table where id=1'

exec(@sqlquery)

set @sqlquery='select * into #tmp_2 from #table_1'

exec(@sqlquery)
```

Output :-

> Invalid object name '#table_1'.

Comment: Each query you run dynamically runs in its own context, so the temp table is dropped after the first query runs. You need to create the temp table in the outer context before you call any dynamic SQL.

Comment: Does the session matters in this scenario, as per the temp table property it should be accessible throughout the session!

Comment: `it should be accessible throughout the session` That is accessibility. Local temp table is only *visible* in the *current session*. But temp table is also automatically *drop* when it is *out of scope*. When `exec()` ends, it is out of scope. Please refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables) for more details

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods to solve this

**1. Declare your temp table as `##table_1` in stead of `#table_1`**

Now your temp table will be accessible in the entire session, and even in other sessions.

This works for me without errors

```
declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max)='select UserID into ##table_1 from tblUser'

exec(@sqlquery)

set @sqlquery='select * into #tmp_2 from ##table_1'

exec(@sqlquery)
```

See also the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#database-scoped-global-temporary-tables-azure-sql-database)

**2. Declare your #table_1 outside the scope of the exec(@SqlQuery)**

```
create table #table_1 (id int)

declare @sqlquery nvarchar(max)='select UserID into #table_1 from tblUser'

exec(@sqlquery)

set @sqlquery='select * into #tmp_2 from #table_1'

exec(@sqlquery)
```

This will work because you create the temp table outside the scope of the exec(@SqlQuery)

Comment: we know this, but from performance point of view this is much worst as it has to wait for all active session to be completed inorder to destory this global temp table.

Comment: @nishantdamani I edited my answer to show how you can do it with the temp table you want, so it only lives in this session